# How to turn off Velocity unit testing in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js, velocity

I'm using the **mike:mocha** package and I'm trying to figure out how to disable testing.

There are times when I have to demo the app I'm working on in my local machine. For those situations, I would like to run the application without the green dot on the top right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some googling I found that running

```
meteor --production run
```

takes care of this.

> **Note:** As @cannotto90 noted below, running this command will minifiy the client code and code refresh will not be in effect. To get back to coding, you
>   will need to stop meteor first `ctrl+c` and run meteor again using the
>   `meteor` command.

Comment: Be aware that this have side effects due to `production` mode, including minification of client code and no code refresh.

Comment: @canotto90 Thanks for the info, I'll update the answer to include this.

Comment: This seems to mean that the --test switch no longer has any meaning, right?  I think it is a mistake.

Comment: See this issue https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity/issues/270

Answer (score 4):

Here's a cheap work-around trick from the spiritually perverse :

veloff.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #
 meteor remove xolvio:cucumber
 meteor run
```

velon.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #
 meteor add xolvio:cucumber
 meteor run
```

Works for me.  In your case swap in mike:mocha instead of xolvio:cucumber, of course.  I'm guessing it'll work the same.

Your tests directory will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a mocha-esque alternative for testing Meteor app, that doesn't use Velocity and only runs tests under demand. It's only server-side currently. You might find it useful: https://github.com/taromero/latte.