# run meteor without test

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, meteor-velocity

I have installed mike:mocha in my meteor.js project and have written some tests.
Now whenever I run my app, it starts another clone and starts testing
This makes my system too slow to work.

Is there a way to do test only when I want or a way to stop testing when I want?

Thank you

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate to

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243106/how-to-turn-off-velocity-unit-testing-in-meteor

Comment: You might find my https://github.com/taromero/latte lib useful. It only runs tests on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

Set VELOCITY=0 as an environment variable

Comment: Okay, I did `VELOCITY=0 meteor` it says `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'registerTestingFramework'`

Comment: https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity/issues/270
it says VELOCITY=0 doesnt work for mike:mocha

Comment: this is the correct way to do it. mike:mocha seems to have a bug and I would suggest you post an issue there.